# Numpy summarize one array by values of another

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find a vectorized way to accomplish the follwing:

Say I have an array of x and y values. Note that the x values are not always ints and CAN be negative:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-1,-1,-1,3,2,2,2,5,4,4], dtype=float)
y = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1])
```

I want to group the y array by the sorted, unique values of the x array and summarize the counts for each y class. So the example above would look like this:

```
array([[ 2.,  1.],
      [ 2.,  1.],
      [ 0.,  1.],
      [ 1.,  1.],
      [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Where the first column represents the count of '0' values for each unique value of x and the second column represents the count of '1' values for each unique value of x.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
x_sorted, y_sorted = x[x.argsort()], y[x.argsort()]

def collapse(x_sorted, y_sorted):
     uniq_ids = np.unique(x_sorted, return_index=True)[1]
     y_collapsed = np.zeros((len(uniq_ids), 2))
     x_collapsed = x_sorted[uniq_ids]
     for idx, y in enumerate(np.split(y_sorted, uniq_ids[1:])):
          y_collapsed[idx,0] = (y == 0).sum()
          y_collapsed[idx,1] = (y == 1).sum()
     return (x_collapsed, y_collapsed)

collapse(x_sorted, y_sorted)
(array([-1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([[ 2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]))
```

This doesn't seem very much in the spirit of numpy, however, and I'm hoping some vectorized method exists for this kind of operation. I am trying to do this without resorting to pandas. I know that library has a very convenient groupby operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `x` is `float`. I would do this:

```
In [136]:

np.array([(x[y==0]==np.unique(x)[..., np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1),
          (x[y==1]==np.unique(x)[..., np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)]).T
Out[136]:
array([[2, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

Speed:

```
In [152]:

%%timeit
ux=np.unique(x)[..., np.newaxis]
np.array([(x[y==0]==ux).sum(axis=1),
          (x[y==1]==ux).sum(axis=1)]).T
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.7 µs per loop
```

Solution @seikichi

```
In [151]:

%%timeit
>>> x = np.array([1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 3.3, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 5.5, 4.4, 4.4])
>>> y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> r = np.r_[np.unique(x), np.inf]
>>> np.concatenate([[np.histogram(x[y == v], r)[0]] for v in sorted(set(y))]).T
1000 loops, best of 3: 388 µs per loop
```

For more general cases when `y` is not just `{0,1}`, as @askewchan pointed out:

```
In [155]:

%%timeit
ux=np.unique(x)[..., np.newaxis]
uy=np.unique(y)
np.asanyarray([(x[y==v]==ux).sum(axis=1) for v in uy]).T
10000 loops, best of 3: 116 µs per loop
```

To explain the broadcasting further, see this example:

```
In [5]:

np.unique(a)
Out[5]:
array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  1.1,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  2. ])
In [8]:

np.unique(a)[...,np.newaxis] #what [..., np.newaxis] will do:
Out[8]:
array([[ 0. ],
       [ 0.2],
       [ 0.4],
       [ 0.5],
       [ 0.6],
       [ 1.1],
       [ 1.5],
       [ 1.6],
       [ 1.7],
       [ 2. ]])
In [10]:

(a==np.unique(a)[...,np.newaxis]).astype('int') #then we can boardcast (converted to int for readability)
Out[10]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
In [11]:

(a==np.unique(a)[...,np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1) #getting the count of unique value becomes summing among the 2nd axis
Out[11]:
array([1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3])
```

Comment: You run `np.unique(x)` twice with each call.  Also you did the `sorted(set(y))` manually, which only works for small sets of `y`.

Comment: Well you included timings :P

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I'm accepting as it is indeed faster for my use case. Can you explain or point me to where I can read about the `[..., np.newaxis]` pattern? I have never seen that before.

Comment: It is equivalent to `a.shape = a.shape + (1,)` so that you can "broadcast" with it.  Very useful, so play around with it: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: @Zelazny7, besides ackewchan's link, I also added an example. See above.

Comment: Is there a built-in limit to the size of arrays that can be broadcast together? When I use an x that has a large number of unique values (over 10,000), the comparison `x[y==0]==np.unique(x)[..., np.newaxis]` returns a single bool value as if Python is testing whether the objects are the same.

Comment: I created another question expanding on my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567259/broadcasting-large-arrays-in-numpy-changes-result-type

Answer (score 4):

How about the following code? (use [`numpy.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html))

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,1,1,3,2,2,2,5,4,4])
>>> y = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1])
>>> xmax = x.max()
>>> numpy.concatenate([[numpy.bincount(x[y == v], minlength=xmax + 1)] for v in sorted(set(y))], axis=0)[:, 1:].T
array([[2, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

---

**UPDATE :**
Thanks @askewchan !

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 3.3, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 5.5, 4.4, 4.4])
>>> y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> r = np.r_[np.unique(x), np.inf]
>>> np.array([np.histogram(x[y == v], r)[0] for v in sorted(set(y))]).T
array([[2, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

Comment: Sorry, neglected to include that my x values are not necessarily int

Comment: You could replace `bincount` with `np.histogram(x, np.r_[np.unique(x), np.inf]))`

Comment: Or even better: `np.bincount(np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)[1])`

Answer (score 3):

`np.unique` and `np.bincount` are your friends here. The following should work for any type of the inputs, not neccessarily small consecutive integers:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4])
>>> y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1])
>>> 
>>> x_unq, x_idx = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
>>> y_unq, y_idx = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
>>> 
>>> np.column_stack(np.bincount(x_idx, y_idx == j) for j in range(len(y_unq)))
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

You can extract the row and column labels also:

```
>>> x_unq
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> y_unq
array([0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but I think it should work. Basically all I do is grab the values from `y` based on `x` being the value in question.

```
uniques = list(set(x))
uniques.sort()
lu = len(uniques)
res = np.zeros(lu * 2).reshape(lu, 2)
for i, v in enumerate(uniques):
    cur = y[x == v]
    s = cur.sum()
    res[i, 0] = len(cur) - s
    res[i, 1] = s
```

another way is to use `numpy MaskedArrays`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

```
y = y[np.argsort(x)]

b = np.bincount(x)
b = b[b!=0]

ans = np.array([[i.shape[0], i.sum()] for i in np.split(y, np.cumsum(b))[:-1]])

ans[:,0] -= ans[:,1]

print(ans)
#array([[2, 1],
#   [2, 1],
#   [0, 1],
#   [1, 1],
#   [0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Timing:

```
 @seikichi solution:
 10000 loops, best of 3: 37.2 µs per loop

 @acushner solution:
 10000 loops, best of 3: 65.4 µs per loop

 @SaulloCastro solution:
 10000 loops, best of 3: 154 µs per loop
```