# Broadcasting large arrays in numpy changes result type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to summarize one numpy array by the values of another. The solution offered from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516059/numpy-summarize-one-array-by-values-of-another) was very helpful and indeed works when the number of unique values of x is small. However, as I the number of unique values of x increases some odd behavior happens:

```
In [1]:
n = [1000, 10000, 100000]

for i in n:
     x = np.array(range(i))
     y = np.zeros(len(x))
     y[x % 2 == 0] = 1

     # unique values of x
     ux = np.unique(x)[..., np.newaxis]
     res = x[y==0]==ux
     print type(res)

Out[1]:
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'bool'>
```

Once the number of unique x values exceeds a certain threshold, the type resulting from the broadcast is a bool instead of an array. Is an upper limit to the size of a broadcast operation in numpy?

EDIT:
Version info

```
In [2]: np.__version__, sys.version
Out[2]:
('1.8.0',
 '2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-1 (32-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 14:30:37) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]')
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your example.  It sounds like you're winding up with a situation where there's only one item in `x[y==0]`.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. I get arrays for all 3 test cases.

Comment: Even if there's only one item in `x[y==0]`, it'd still be an array, and the `==` would still also produce an array.

Comment: What versions of NumPy and Python are you on?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you wouldn't have `import numpy as np` already executed on line 1 of an IPython session. Is it possible that whatever's doing that also messes with some NumPy settings?

Comment: It also happens when I execute the script from the command prompt

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I really suspect it is a `32bit` issue. Like most of us (I hope), I am running `OSX x86_64`.

Comment: Looks like when `n=100000` the operation takes 4.65GB on my machine. Therefore I don't think a `32bit` system can even take that. `n=10000` will probably be fine as it may be expect to require 1/100 as much RAM.

Comment: I think you're right. Replacing n with `n = [1000, 10000, 46340, 46341]` (the sqrt of `sys.maxint`) fails at 46341 but not 46340. Care to make it an answer and I can mark it as the solution

Comment: You should post that answer yourself @Zelazny7. Please do, it is useful information.